# Create run time TTabItem , firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Seems like i need some help with a project.
I have a routine , that constructs run time multiple TabItems on to a page control in firemonkey, and i want to have a close button on the tab.
The new tab has a checkbox for the close button loading from the styler of the tabitems.
The page has a default tab, and within some button, i am adding run time the new tab items.
I have managed to apply the event for closing the default tab page, but doesn't work within the run time created tab pages. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the piece of code for the runtime tabitems

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  t : TTabItem;
  o : TFmxObject;
  i : Integer;
  c : TControl;
begin
  t := TTabItem.Create(pgeControl);

  t.Parent := pgeControl;

  o := FindBinding('imgCloseTabPage');
  if o<>nil then
  begin
    for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
    begin
      if Components[i] is TCheckBox then
      begin
        TCheckBox(Components[i]).OnClick := CheckBox1Click;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  if pgeControl.TabCount - 1 <= nTab then
  begin
    nTab := nTab + 1;
    t.Index := nTab
  end
  else
  begin
    t.Index := pgeControl.TabCount - 1;
    nTab := pgeControl.TabCount - 1;
  end;
  t.Tag := nTab;

  t.Text := 'Some text...' + ' ' + IntToStr(nTab);
  t.Name := 'tabPatient' + IntToStr(nTab);

  t.Height := 35;
  t.Width := 250;
  t.Margins.Top := 0;
  t.Margins.Left := 0;
  t.Margins.Bottom := 0;
  t.Margins.Right := 0;

  t.Padding.Top := -5;
  t.Padding.Left := 0;
  t.Padding.Bottom := 0;
  t.Padding.Right := 0;

  t.TextAlign := TTextAlign.taLeading;
  t.Width := (Length(t.Text) * 6 ) + 60;
  t.Font.Size := 15;
  t.StyleLookup := 'tabMainStyle1';

  l := TLayout.Create(t);
  l.Parent := t;
  l.Align := TAlignLayout.alClient;
  l.Margins.Top := -5;
  l.Margins.Left := 5;
  l.Margins.Right := 5;
  l.Margins.Bottom := 5;
  l.Padding.Top := 0;
  l.Padding.Left := 0;
  l.Padding.Bottom := 0;
  l.Padding.Right := 0;

  pgeControl.ActiveTab := pgeControl.Tabs[pgeControl.TabCount - 1];
end;
```

Comment: Are you creating a new checkbox for every new tabitem?

Comment: No, i don't create checkbox for every new tabitem, its on a styler, witch loads within the tab items when they are created run time wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud call FindBinding **after** having applyed the custom style. Currently you call this **before**, so it can't find the object. Additionally there was a mistake when you was looking for the object.

so put this

```
o := t.FindBinding('imgCloseTabPage');
if o<>nil then
begin
  if o is TCheckBox then
    TCheckBox(o).OnClick := CheckBox1Click;
end;
```

after

```
t.StyleLookup := 'tabMainStyle1';
```

and the event should assigned.

Comment: Thank you for you help, but is seems not to work.
Even if i change the code by your suggestion, the event doesn't fire.
The event is ignored either cases.
Do you have any other idea;
I can sent you the hole project, i case needed.
Thank you again.
Best regards

Comment: Forget my comment.I have managed to solve, with you help.Thank you very much.