# How to implement a close button on every tab of TTabControl in Delphi XE3 FireMonkey 2?

Tags: delphi, tabcontrol, delphi-xe3, firemonkey-fm2

I am trying to create a browser-style TabControl with a small close button on every tab in FireMonkey FM2.

Since there are no TTabsheet and TPageControl components in FM2, I could not use the answer from "[How to implement a close button for a TTabsheet of a TPageControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201850/how-to-implement-a-close-button-for-a-ttabsheet-of-a-tpagecontrol)". This code gives too many undeclared functions and variables that are not longer supported in FM2, I guess.

I don't want to use any third-part components because you never know if they are going to support the next version of Delphi :)

I can provide the full code that works fine in Delphi XE3 VCL (but not FireMonkey):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls, Math, Vcl.Themes;

type
  TFormMain = class(TForm)
    PageControlCloseButton: TPageControl;
    TabSheet1: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet2: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet3: TTabSheet;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PageControlCloseButtonMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PageControlCloseButtonMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure PageControlCloseButtonMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure PageControlCloseButtonMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure PageControlCloseButtonDrawTab(Control: TCustomTabControl; TabIndex: Integer; const Rect: TRect; Active: Boolean);

  private
    FCloseButtonsRect: array of TRect;
    FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex: Integer;
    FCloseButtonShowPushed: Boolean;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FormMain: TFormMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFormMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin

  PageControlCloseButton.TabWidth := 150;
  PageControlCloseButton.OwnerDraw := True;

  //should be done on every change of the page count
  SetLength(FCloseButtonsRect, PageControlCloseButton.PageCount);
  FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex := -1;

  for I := 0 to Length(FCloseButtonsRect) - 1 do
  begin
    FCloseButtonsRect[I] := Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  end;

end;

procedure TFormMain.PageControlCloseButtonDrawTab(Control: TCustomTabControl; TabIndex: Integer; const Rect: TRect; Active: Boolean);
var
  CloseBtnSize: Integer;
  PageControl: TPageControl;
  TabCaption: TPoint;
  CloseBtnRect: TRect;
  CloseBtnDrawState: Cardinal;
  CloseBtnDrawDetails: TThemedElementDetails;
const
  UseThemes: boolean=true;
begin
  PageControl := Control as TPageControl;

  if InRange(TabIndex, 0, Length(FCloseButtonsRect) - 1) then
  begin
    CloseBtnSize := 14;
    TabCaption.Y := Rect.Top + 3;

    if Active then
    begin
      CloseBtnRect.Top := Rect.Top + 4;
      CloseBtnRect.Right := Rect.Right - 5;
      TabCaption.X := Rect.Left + 6;
    end
    else
    begin
      CloseBtnRect.Top := Rect.Top + 3;
      CloseBtnRect.Right := Rect.Right - 5;
      TabCaption.X := Rect.Left + 3;
    end;

    CloseBtnRect.Bottom := CloseBtnRect.Top + CloseBtnSize;
    CloseBtnRect.Left := CloseBtnRect.Right - CloseBtnSize;
    FCloseButtonsRect[TabIndex] := CloseBtnRect;

    PageControl.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    PageControl.Canvas.TextOut(TabCaption.X, TabCaption.Y, PageControl.Pages[TabIndex].Caption);


    if not UseThemes then
    begin
      if (FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex = TabIndex) and FCloseButtonShowPushed then
        CloseBtnDrawState := DFCS_CAPTIONCLOSE + DFCS_PUSHED
      else
        CloseBtnDrawState := DFCS_CAPTIONCLOSE;

        DrawFrameControl(PageControl.Canvas.Handle,
        FCloseButtonsRect[TabIndex], DFC_CAPTION, CloseBtnDrawState);
    end
    else
    begin
      Dec(FCloseButtonsRect[TabIndex].Left);

      if (FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex = TabIndex) and FCloseButtonShowPushed then
        CloseBtnDrawDetails := ThemeServices.GetElementDetails(twCloseButtonPushed)
      else
        CloseBtnDrawDetails := ThemeServices.GetElementDetails(twCloseButtonNormal);

      ThemeServices.DrawElement(PageControl.Canvas.Handle, CloseBtnDrawDetails,
        FCloseButtonsRect[TabIndex]);
    end;

  end;
end;

procedure TFormMain.PageControlCloseButtonMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if Button = mbLeft then
  begin
    for I := 0 to Length(FCloseButtonsRect) - 1 do
    begin
      if PtInRect(FCloseButtonsRect[I], Point(X, Y)) then
      begin
        FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex := I;
        FCloseButtonShowPushed := True;
        PageControlCloseButton.Repaint;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormMain.PageControlCloseButtonMouseMove(Sender: TObject;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  Inside: Boolean;
begin
   if (ssLeft in Shift) and (FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex >= 0) then
  begin
    Inside := PtInRect(FCloseButtonsRect[FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex], Point(X, Y));

    if FCloseButtonShowPushed <> Inside then
    begin
      FCloseButtonShowPushed := Inside;
      PageControlCloseButton.Repaint;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormMain.PageControlCloseButtonMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
var
  PageControl: TPageControl;
begin
   FCloseButtonShowPushed := False;
  PageControlCloseButton.Repaint;
end;

procedure TFormMain.PageControlCloseButtonMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  PageControl: TPageControl;
begin

  if (Button = mbLeft) and (FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex >= 0) then
  begin
    if PtInRect(FCloseButtonsRect[FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex], Point(X, Y)) then
    begin
      PageControlCloseButton.Pages[PageControlCloseButton.ActivePageIndex].TabVisible := false;
      PageControlCloseButton.ActivePageIndex := 0;

      FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex := -1;
      PageControlCloseButton.Repaint;
    end;
  end;
 end;

end.
```

Comment: As you said, there are no TTabsheet and TPageControl on FMX, but you can use TTabControl in 'Common Controls'

Comment: Yes, I am using TTabControl in Firemonkey and cannot solve the compile problem of the code above :)

Comment: I can't see any TTabControl in your source code above. Your code is using TPageControl (and TTabsheet). You must replace TPageControl with TTabControl, and TTabSheet with TTabItem. No TRect in FMX, so you must replace TRect with TRectF.

Comment: You can't just use code from the VCL in FMX, they are different UI frameworks. You should remove all code from the question and rephrase it without any references to the VCL controls.

Comment: The OP of this question seems to have solved the problem, but some key pieces are missing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134965/create-run-time-ttabitem-firemonkey

Answer (score 0):

On github there is an open source component that extend the base FMX TTabControl at this link https://github.com/jkour/neTabControl where you can understand how to do it by your self.