# Looking for a 3rd party tabcontrol in Delphi FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, tabcontrol, firemonkey

I am looking for a alternative to [Raize](http://www.raize.com/DevTools/RzComps/Default.asp) components' tab control.

I would like to have the ability to add close button at the top of each page and I want to use slanted tabs and colors on the tabs. Oh, and I'm using FireMonkey 2.

//I know that raize does not support firmonkey.

Comment: So is your question "Are there any 3rd party TabControls with a close button?" or is it "How to add a close button to the standard TabControl?". What does it have to do with Raize components? AFAIK Raize doesn't even have FMX support?

Comment: Have you checked this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134965/create-run-time-ttabitem-firemonkey

Comment: This question is related as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580733/how-to-implement-a-close-button-on-every-tab-of-ttabcontrol-in-delphi-xe3-firemo

Comment: I have looked at both questions and they are not what this is about i want a 3rd party control for firemonkey.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify it then. Write exactly what your problem is and don't ask for multiple things at once.

Comment: Is the question ok now?

Comment: Yes, it's better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firemonkey has it's own `TTabControl` in the `Common Controls` page (by default). You can style this using a `TStylebook`. For example, I'm quite confident it's possible to add a close button onto the tab itself.

After all, FMX is a vector-based framework and so all visual elements must exist within the style. You'll probably want to load a style into a TStylebook for this, as I'm unable to find a way to load the default style into one. Navigate down to `tabitemstyle`, and from there you'll be able to tweak the visual appearance of it. Simply add a close button as you'd like (alignment, layout, etc).

Back in your application code, you'll be looking to use the `FindStyleResource` routine in order to setup the code (XE2 uses `FindBinding` and as such you'd set the `BindingName` property instead). I'm going to assume your close button is called 'CloseButton' (without the quotes);

```
var
  MyTab : TTabItem;
begin
  MyTab := ((TabItem1 as TTabItem).FindStyleResource('CloseButton') as TButton).OnClick := TabClose;
end;
```

You'd want to add that code when you initially create the tab, or if creating all the tabs at design time, you'll want to run it at FormCreate. You're basically telling it that when CloseButton is clicked, that you want to call the notify event/procedure `TabClose`. This procedure is identical to a button click.

You could go so far as changing the `StyleName` property of the tab to be `CloseButton`+Index_of_tab.

Now, as for the code to close the tab itself, something like this **untested example** may work, though you'll want to iterate on it.

```
procedure TForm1.TabClose(Sender: TObject);
var
  _mytab : Integer;
  _activetab : Integer;
begin
  _activetab := ((Sender as TTabItem).Parent as TTabControl).ActiveTab.Index;
  _mytab := ((Sender as TTabItem).Parent as TTabControl).ActiveTab.Index;
  ((Sender as TTabItem).Parent as TTabControl).Tabs[_MyTab].Free;
  ((Sender as TTabItem).Parent as TTabControl).TabIndex := _activetab;
end;
```

Now, this is the clever part, and exploits the design of the framework. When you click on a style element that's inside another element, by default, it'll select the parent element. In this example, it'll select the tab that contains the close button the user clicked on. From this, it'll then close that tab (technically, it'll free it, I've not dealt with tabs much in development so you'll want to look into the proper method of 'closing' them).

There is one problem with this though; You'll probably want to find a better way of detecting the previously active tab if you wish to switch back to it. Right now, it'll simply open the tab that was after the tab you just closed (since the tabcount is now 1 less, the active tab index selects the next physical tab). You'll probably be able to do this by splitting the `_activetab` code off elsewhere.

---

I've done similar things with some of my own programs, and this is how I usually create 'hybrid' components. You're essentially exploiting the modular design of the framework to make it do what you want it to do, without having to rely on third party components.

Comment: Ok ill let you know how this go's. Im a bit busy.

Answer (score 1):

Since FMX is a pretty young framework there aren't many 3rd party component vendors that support it yet.

I haven't seen any 3rd party TabControl component for FMX and a quick Google search suggests there aren't any. So you might be out of luck.

Comment: You may be right this is what happens when you move to fast to a new platform.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old query but in case anyone is still looking for tabs with close buttons and slanted tab sides, check out TMSSoftware's TTMSFMXTabSet. I'm using it in a current development project and it is working fine.